# Why Application.OnMessage is not called when popup menu is shown?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I use an Application.OnMessage event handler to process messages (notifications) from other threads in my program. And I found that if popup menu is active (opened), this event handler is not called. The test code is below (it is without threads but the principle is the same):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage := ApplicationEvents1Message;
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_USER then
    Beep();
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostThreadMessage(GetCurrentThreadId, WM_USER, 0, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

`OnMessage` is called from the main thread's message loop. This message loop is implemented in Delphi's VCL library code. Hence this library code has the opportunity to call the event handler for `OnMessage`.

The popup menu is shown by calling the Win32 function `TrackPopupMenuEx`. This function implements a modal message loop to run the tracking UI for the menu. Because this message loop is implemented in Win32 code the VCL code does not have an opportunity to fire the `OnMessage` event. The Win32 code knows nothing of the VCL and runs a plain message loop. Messages are serviced and dispatched but no VCL specific code can be executed.

This is a perfect example of why `PostThreadMessage` should be avoided. Only if you control every message loop can it be used. Other points of failure include system message dialogs, drag and drop modal loops, window move/size modal loops.

You should stop using `PostThreadMesaage`. Instead create a window handle in the main thread using `AllocateHWnd`. Post messages to that window from your worker threads.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Allow me to clarify: in the secondary threads (they have their own message queue) it is safe to receive messages sent via PostThreadMessage and only if a message is sent from the secondary thread to the main thread of the program, it is better to process a message in a window procedure of separate window?

Comment: If the secondary threads have no UI, as they shouldn't,  and nothing else there runs a message loop, other than your code, then thread messages are safe there. For consistency you might find it cleaner to use a window to receive messages. However, AllocateHWnd cannot be called away from the main thread due to long broken design of VCL. So you'd have to replace that with your own version, easy enough to do but annoying.

Comment: [Thread messages are eaten by modal loops](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050426-18/?p=35783)

Comment: A slightly easier approach, then to make AllocateHWnd thread safe, can be to use a thread that could synchronize with the main thread when a message arrives. I think... Maybe not as I don't know what would it take to do the former.

Comment: @sertac how do you get a message to the thread since you can't call AllocateHWnd in the thread

Comment: @David - A thread message, with HWnd 0. I just tested a proof of concept, the thread just calls `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, PHandle(nil)^, False, INFINITE, QS_POSTMESSAGE)`. It receives any message sent by PostThreadMessage since modality only effects the main thread. It then synchronizes with the main thread without problem since synchronization is not effected by the main thread's modal state.